# OutOfMemoryError when try to receive large json response : Android

Tags: android, json, jackson, out-of-memory, android-volley

I am facing **OutofMemoryError** exception, when I try to convert the json response to string

Here is the code I tried

```
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
 if(entity != null) {
    contentAsString = EntityUtils.toString(entity); // error
 }
```

I tried with volley and Retrofit Network libraries as well but facing the same issue. Pls suggest...

Comment: You tried in emulator or device?

Comment: Tried adding `android:largeHeap="true"` to manifest?

Comment: Do you receive an base64 encoded image?

Comment: Do you have control over your backend? how big is your json response?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245650/jsonarray-throwing-out-of-memory-exception-in-android

Comment: @PatrickMA json not contains any images

Comment: @AristoMichael but in general it could contain images. 
What does the response contain? And how big (in bytes) is the response?

Comment: @PatrickMA my json datas contains only strings

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Set the largeHeap="true" in your AndroidManifest.xml**

```
  <application
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Let me know if this works for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your manifest

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```